# Adding a flash notice to a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to add a flash notice when someone clicks a static link?

```
<%= link_to "show clip", sign_up_page_path, notice: "You must sign up or sign in to view clips." %>
```

The fact is, it's not an authentication issue because the content is static, I'd just like to manually link to the sign-up page and throw a notice stating that the user must "sign up or sign in to view clips."

Comment: so you want to show this notice even if the user is signed up and signed in?

Comment: No, so here's an example.. you visit the website, there are a bunch of clips on the landing page, although you should only be able to view them when signed in.. However, these clips on the landing page are just static images that link to the sign-up page. I'd like to display a notice when a user clicks the clip image that says "You must sign up or sign in to view clips." and links to the sign-up page.

Comment: Once you decide which system you're going to use to display a popup message, it's just a case of adding that to an onclick.  eg `<%= link_to "show clip", sign_up_page_path, onclick: "alert('You must sign up or sign in to view clips.')" %>`.  This uses the standard browser alerts which are kind of nasty.  If you want a nicer style of popup then i'd recommend googling for jquery plugins to do this, or a larger library like bootstrap etc if you're already going down that route.

Comment: Got it no worries! The modal worked

Answer (score 1):

### Flash:

If you look at [`rail guides`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash), it says

`The flash is a special part of the session which is cleared with each request. This means that values stored there will only be available in the next request, which is useful for passing error messages etc.`

### link_to:

If you look at your link_to syntax:

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
# url is a String; you can use URL helpers like
# posts_path
```

`Is it possible to add a flash notice when someone clicks a static link`

*The answer would be **no** because if you look at link_to syntax then it just doesn't allow you to set a flash message*

### Fix:

As `@Max Williams` pointed out you can **use browsers dialog box** to alert user to sign up and then redirect him/her to your sign up page. You can also use bootstraps modal to display your message but personally i think [***`bootstrap popover`***](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) would be much better than a modal or you can simply display a [**`tooltip`**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) asking user to sign up or sign in

Answer (score 0):

One another solution the Rails way:

1. Check if the user is signed up : `if current_user.present? SIGN_UP_LINK else ... end`
2. In the else block: redirect to the same page with a get variable: `<%= link_to "show clip", same_page_path(check: "true") %>`
3. In your controller:

```
if params[:check].present?
  flash.alert = "You must sign up or sign in to view clips."
end
```

I hope this is useful!